# Deleting random elements of a list while going through the list

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator

From what I read, it is safe to remove elements while iterating through a list. (instead of using the simple for each loop).

Suppose I have a list of elements, and I want to visit all of the elements, but while I visit each element, I will visit its neighbours (note that I have a map for each element which will give me its neighbours), thus I will
have to remove other elements from the original list. Thus I cannot use
iterator.remove().

What is a good way to do this, that is to say, remove elements from the list that I am going through without being at the position with the iterator?

One idea I had was the following, have my elements in a map, with value as
a boolean, (true for visited, and false otherwise).
Thus, I go through my list, and for each element i set it visited true, and if one if its neighbours I also see while visiting that element, I will also set them as true.

Comment: can you give more details or some sudo code of what you want to do ?

Comment: Why do you wanted to delete the elements? If the point is not visiting the same node twice, mark the node as "visited" by adding a flag to the object. No need to remove the node or add a second hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead of a foreach to iterate over the items. Then remove as you see fit.  Here is an example of removing even elements from the List

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ints.add(100);
            ints.add(1);
            ints.add(15);
            ints.add(42);
            ints.add(187);

            System.out.println("Original List");
            for(Integer i: ints){
                    System.out.println(i);
            }

            /* Remove any even elements from the list */
            for(int i=0; i < ints.size(); i++){
                    if(ints.get(i) % 2 == 0){
                            ints.remove(i);
                    }
            }

            System.out.println("\nModified List");
            for(Integer i: ints){
                    System.out.println(i);
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you are talking about an input list that is an `ArrayList`.

The following approach will give you `O(N)` behaviour (for at least OpenJDK Java 6 through Java 8):

1. Create a HashSet.
2. Iterate over the elements of your input list:

   1. Visit the element and add it to the set if it should be removed
   2. Visit the neighbours of the element and add to the set any one that should be removed.
3. Call `list.removeAll(set)`.

The `removeAll` method for `ArrayList` calls an internal `batchRemove` method ([see here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.batchRemove%28java.util.Collection%2Cboolean%29)).  This method performs a single pass over the `ArrayList`'s backing array, removing elements and filling the holes.  It tests each element to see if it should be removed by calling `set.contains(elem)`.  For a `HashSet` that test is `O(1)`, and hence the `removeAll(set)` call is `O(N)` where `N` is the list size.

---

It is interesting to note that `arrayList.removeAll(hashSet)` will be `O(N)` where `N` is the list length, but removing the same elements like this:

```
for (Iterator it = arrayList.iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
      if (hashSet.contains(it.next())) {
             it.remove();
      }
}
```

will be `O(NM)` where `N` is the list length and `M` is the set size.